# Proving that $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \log(1+|x-y|)$ for all $x,y \in R$ is onto

Tags: functions, continuity

How do I prove that it is onto?The function $f$ is continuous  in $\mathbb{R}$. I have thought about it without any progress. Some hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there exist $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\ne c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

By continuity and intermediate value theorem, one must have either $f(x)<c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $f(x)>c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Without loss of generality we assume $f(x)>c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (for the other case we can replace $f$ with $-f$)

Now we let $y=0$ in the original identity:

$\log(1+|x|)\le|f(x)-f(0)|\le|f(x)|+|f(0)|$, so:

$|f(x)|\ge\log(1+|x|)-|f(0)|$

It follows that $|f(x)|\to\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. But $f(x)>c$, so we must have $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$

Using continuity, we can find $x_1<0$ and $x_2>0$ such that:

$f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(0)+1$

Which we plug in the original equation and we get:

$\log(1+|x_2-x_1|)\le 0$

which is clearly a contradiction.