# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a cont. function that statisfies $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \log(1+|x-y|)$ then the function $f$ is bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I have been able to show the injectivity part but I am stuck with surjectivity.I think we need to use the intermediate value theorem somehow but I don't know how?Also what if $\log(1+|x-y|)$ is replaced by any other surjective function will the function still be surjective?

Comment: Hint :  Show that $\lim_{\pm \infty}f = \pm \infty$ and use the fact that $f$ is strictly monotonous, since it is injective and continuous.

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf(x)-f(y)%7C%20%5Cge%20%5Clog(1%2B%7Cx-y%7C)%24

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668134, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728219, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3786005.